# parsing html with issues in android app

Tags: java, android, html, header, jsoup

I'm trying to parse html of webpage in my android app using Jsoup, I have encountered a problem with this specific page: http://techmvs.technion.ac.il/cics/wmn/wmngrad?ORD=1

this string:

```
<!doctype html public "-//ietf//dtd html 3.0//en">:
```

appears in the headers sections while it is obviously not one, when I try to execute the Jsoup connection in the next code line:

```
Response r = Jsoup.connect("http://techmvs.technion.ac.il/cics/wmn/wmngrad?ORD=1").followRedirects(true).execute();
```

it appears to take this bad header as a header with empty name and empty value, which causes an exception, here is the stack:

```
W: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name must not be empty
W:     at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Base.header(HttpConnection.java:292)
W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.processResponseHeaders(HttpConnection.java:828)
W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.setupFromConnection(HttpConnection.java:772)
W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:569)
W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
W:     at gavi_anna_netanel.com.madomes.ug_login.GradesParser$GradesFetcher.getGradesList(GradesParser.java:48)
W:     at gavi_anna_netanel.com.madomes.ug_login.GradesParser$GradesFetcher.doInBackground(GradesParser.java:32)
W:     at gavi_anna_netanel.com.madomes.ug_login.GradesParser$GradesFetcher.doInBackground(GradesParser.java:28)
W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
W:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

important to say that as a JAVA project it did work (although the bad header appeared in the html as well).

is there a way to tell Jsoup to ignore bad headers and connect to the url anyway?
if not, is there another client that will not fail on android because of this bad header?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use an XML parser instead HTML parser and `parseBodyFragment()` instead `parse()`?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Comment: the redirections give the url i actually want to parse, so i don't have the html yet, because it doesn't connect